# Integrity eror not null constraint failed

Tags: django, exception, integrity

Exception Type:  IntegrityError

Exception Value:

NOT NULL constraint failed: Cart.cart_id

```py
#mymodel:
class Cart(models.Model):          

    cart_id=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)

    def _cart_id(request):
        cart=request.session.session_key
        if not cart:
            cart=request.session.create()

    def add_cart(request,product_id):
        product=Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        try:
            cart=Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        except Cart.DoesNotExist:
            cart=Cart.objects.create(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        cart.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `Cart` model with `cart_id=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Your function **_cart_id()** return nothing and you are using it for getting or creating cart_id.

```py
class Cart(models.Model):          

    cart_id=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)

    def _cart_id(request):
        cart=request.session.session_key
        if not cart:
            cart=request.session.create()
        return cart

    def add_cart(request, product_id):
        product=Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        try:
            cart=Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        except Cart.DoesNotExist:
            cart=Cart.objects.create(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        cart.save()
```